# Why can only superusers administer information requests?

Tags: joomla-3.9, super-user

I have activated the new privacy suite that came in Joomla 3.9 in a website. It is impressive software: its capabilities and the userfriendly way it is presented.

The documentation tells me that superusers can administer information requests from registered users. (They can request to receive an export of all their personal data, or they can ask to delete all known personal data. The superuser admin can create a data dump and sent them this in the mail, or delete all personal data (login data also) which also anonymises their user account data).
The only users that are allowed to do this are superusers.
It is possible to create an administrator group that has acl rights to create and manage users but without all acl rights a auperuser has. I do not understand why the administrator role is not allowed to handle information requests.
I would like to be able to create an admin group with acl rights that permit users in that group to do this.

I assume this has been discussed by developers of the privacy suite, but I cannot find any trace of these discussions, and of the arguments that led to the decision to let only superusers handle this.

Can someone direct me to these discussions, or tell me why it was decided to do it this way? And even perhaps of ways to change this superuser monopoly?

Regards,
Paul

Comment: Volunteers should not weigh in on _why it was decided to do it this way_ unless they are able to site quotes from an offical source, otherwise the response would be opinion-based and off-topic for this site.  Offering a link to a resource that contains the discussions may be posted as a comment or as a supplement to an answer, but would not constitute a "good" answer on its own.  Essentially, I suppose I am asking volunteers to focus on answering the final question: How to change this superuser monopoly.

Comment: I haven't used the Privacy suite so far and generally I hadn't much time to follow what's up with Joomla recently and the new 3.9 features. So after your question I went in the backend of 3.9.2 and checked about the ACL for the privacy suite, just to find out what you are describing. So that's a fair question to ask... "Why don't we have the standard Joomla ACL capabilities on the Privacy Suite?"

Comment: The discussion in question is here https://github.com/joomla-projects/privacy-framework/issues/11.